# Drag and drop ZK TreeModel issue

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, tree, zk

I'm having problems with drag and drop, I wouldn't like to allow one node to be moved within one own subnode, for example:

1--

```
  |--2

       |--3
```

the node 2 can't be moved to node 3, if this happen node 3 has a new subnode but has no parent. The same can't happen with the node 1 that can't be moved to node 2.

Is there a way to prevent this without to implement a method in my viewmodel?

or this is a bug in the compnent.

I'm using AbstractTreeModel, because my tree can become very big and I want it to be loaded on demand, the most examples on the web are about DefaultTreeModel and I can't adapt this examples to my solution.

I'm using ZK 7.0.0 and any help I will apreciate.

bellow is the code used to implement:

.zul file :

```
<zk>
<separator height="10px" />
<tree id="tree" rows="7" model="@load(vmName.unidadeTreeModel)"
    droppable="true" onDrop="@command('mudaUnidadePai', valor=event)" > 
    <treecols>
        <treecol style="font-weight: bold;">
            <label value="Nome"
                style="font-weight: bold;" />
                <label value="Editar" />
                <label value="Excluir"/>
                <label value="Numero" />
        </treecol>
    </treecols>
    <template name="model">
        <treeitem >
            <treerow draggable="true" droppable="true"                                       
              onDrop="@command('mudaUnidadePai',
              valor=event)">
                <treecell label="@load(each.descricao)">
                        <a  label="Editar"                              
                            onClick="@command('editarSelected', selected=each)" />
                        <a label="Excluir"                               
                            onClick="@command('confirmarExclusaoSelected',  
                           selected=each)" />
                        <label value="@load(each.numero)"/>
                  </treecell>
               </treerow>
           </treeitem>
        </template>
    </tree>
</zk>
```

Here is code of my Abstract tree model :

public class UnidadeTreeModel extends AbstractTreeModel{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3854683349236034878L;

private UnidadeServiceImpl unidadeService;

public UnidadeTreeModel(Unidade unidade) {
    super(unidade);
    unidadeService = (UnidadeServiceImpl) SpringUtil.getBean("unidadeService");
}

public boolean isLeaf(Unidade node) {
    Unidade newNode = unidadeService.atualizar(node);
    return newNode.getUnidades() == null || newNode.getUnidades().size() == 0;
}

public Unidade getChild(Unidade parent, int index) {
    Unidade newParent = unidadeService.atualizar(parent);
    if ((newParent).getUnidades() != null && ((Unidade) newParent).getUnidades().size() > index) {
        return (newParent).getUnidades().get(index);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public int getChildCount(Unidade parent) {
    Unidade newParent = unidadeService.atualizar(parent);
    return ((newParent).getUnidades() != null) ? ((Unidade) newParent).getUnidades().size() : 0;
}

public int getIndexOfChild(Unidade parent, Unidade child) {
    Unidade newParent = unidadeService.atualizar(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < newParent.getUnidades().size(); i++) {
        if (child.equals(newParent.getUnidades().get(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

And Finally part of the code from my viewModel:

@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class OrganizacaoViewModel extends AbstractViewModelEnderecoLista implements IViewModelEnderecoLista, Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5809964914070454399L;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrganizacaoViewModel.class);

@Wire
Tree tree;

@Init
@Override
public void init(@ContextParam(ContextType.SESSION) Session session, @ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component component) {

    setService((UnidadeServiceImpl) SpringUtil.getBean("unidadeService"));
    tipoUnidadeService = (TipoUnidadeServiceImpl) SpringUtil.getBean("tipoUnidadeService");
}

@AfterCompose(superclass = true)
@Override
public void atualizarView() {
    montaArvore();
    atualizarLista();
    BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, OrganizacaoViewModel.this, "*");
}

   public void montaArvore() {

    if (getService().buscarRaiz(true) == null) {

        root = new Unidade();
        root.setNumero("NBASE");
        root.setDescricao("DBASE");
        root.setRaiz(true);
        try {
            getService().gravar(root);
        } catch (DuplicateEntryException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Montar arvore", e);
        }
    }
    if (unidadeTreeModel != null) {
        paths = unidadeTreeModel.getOpenPaths();
    } else {
        unidadeTreeModel = new UnidadeTreeModel(getService().buscarRaiz(true));
    }
    unidadeTreeModel.addOpenPaths(paths);
    tree.setModel(unidadeTreeModel);
    paths = null;
}
@Command
public void mudaUnidadePai(@BindingParam("valor") DropEvent evento) {

    if (evento.getTarget().getId().equals("tree")) {
        // caso unidade seja arrastado para arvore, unidade volta para a raiz
        Treerow row = (Treerow) evento.getDragged();
        Treeitem item = (Treeitem) row.getParent();
        Unidade filho = item.getValue();
        filho.setParent(getService().buscarRaiz(true));
        try {
            getService().gravar(filho);
        } catch (DuplicateEntryException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Mudar unidade pai", e);
        }
    } else {
        // extrai novo filho
        Treerow row = (Treerow) evento.getDragged();
        Treeitem item = (Treeitem) row.getParent();
        Unidade filho = item.getValue();

        Treerow row2 = (Treerow) evento.getTarget();
        Treeitem item2 = (Treeitem) row2.getParent();
        Unidade pai = item2.getValue();
        pai.getUnidades().add(filho);
        filho.setParent(pai);
            try {
                getService().gravar(filho);
            } catch (DuplicateEntryException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Mudae unidade pai", e);
            }
         }
    BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, OrganizacaoViewModel.this, "*");

}
```

}

Comment: Can I see the code that is giving you the problem?

Comment: Ok I posted the code, Thank you !!!

Comment: I'm still struggling with the component to keep the tree consistent, but I can't find anyway a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `true` value for droppable and draggable properties, try to use a string.

More help [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Drag_and_Drop#The_draggable_and_droppable_Properties).

Comment: Hello, thanks to try to help, I already tried to use this aporoach , but not works. The problem when I use a string is that when I drag a line, this line is an entity of type Unidade, as in code, this entity doesn't  have any property  of a tree, like isLeaf, etc, and I can't do nothing to check the element dragged. Another way that I saw is to use EL expression, but I until now I don't know how to do this. Some Suggestion ?

Comment: I think that another way to solve this problem is to collapse all nodes when dragged, in my zul code I have onDrop event and no onDrag. Is there a way to collapse all nodes before drop?

Comment: Solved! the solution was a recursive method to check if the node dragged was in the same structure.